# Error: Can't use string pattern on a byte-like object

Tags: python, regex, string, compilation, byte

I am running this code using Python 3.2.3:

```
regex = '<title>(.+?)</title>'
pattern = re.compile(regex)
```

and then searching the pattern using findall:

```
titles = re.findall(pattern,html)
print(titles)
```

html object gets html code from a specific url.

```
html = response.read()
```

I get the error "Can't use string pattern on a byte-like object". I have tried using:

```
regex = b'<title>(.+?)</title>'
```

but that appends a "b" to my results? Thanks.

Comment: What is `html` and [why are you using a regex to parse HTML?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)

Comment: What's the `html` object? Try using `str(html)`. What happens?

Comment: Which HTML parser for Python do you recommend Ignacio?

Answer (score 2):

`urllib.request` responses give you *bytes*, not unicode strings. That's why the `re` pattern needs to be a `bytes` object too, and you get `bytes` results back again.

You can decode the response using the encoding the server gave you on in the HTTP headers:

```
html = response.read()
# no codec set? We default to UTF-8 instead, a reasonable assumption
codec = response.info().get_param('charset', 'utf8')
html = html.decode(codec)
```

Now you have Unicode and can use unicode regular expressions too.

The above can still lead to `UnicodeDecodeException` errors if the server lied about the encoding or there was no encoding set and the default of UTF-8 was incorrect too.

In any case, return values represented with `b'...'` are `bytes` objects; raw string data not yet decoded to Unicode, and are nothing to worry about if you know the right encoding of the data.

Comment: This typifies a general rule when reading and writing string data: decode your inputs to Unicode when you read them, encode your Unicode strings before you write them. All text inside your program should be handled in Unicode.